# What's the difference between accessing struct members by pointer as opposed to by reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

In "The C++ Programming Language (4th Edition)" Section 2.3.1, Stroustrup shows 3 different ways to access members of a `struct`:

```
void f(Vector v, Vector& rv, Vector* pv)
{
    int i1 = v.sz;    // access through name
    int i2 = rv.sz;   // access through reference
    int i4 = pv->sz;  // access through pointer
}
```

1. I understand that for the first one, `v` is passed-by-value, so a copy of the first argument is put on the function's stack and the value of its size `sz` is stored inside of `i1`.
2. In the second example, `rv` is a reference to the struct passed as the second argument. Because it is a reference, we can access the value referred to by `rv` without a `*` prefix.

I'm not too sure I understand what's going on with `i4`, and why someone would pick the third example over the second (or vice-versa).